# HIDE year from date picker widget

Tags: android, datepicker, field

I am trying to hide the year field from the date picker widget.This may look like a repeated question but the answers given for previous questions are not helping me to hide the year field..

Here goes my code::

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    int month = 0;
    int year = 0;
    int day = 0;
    OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = null;
    CustomDatePickerDialog dp = new CustomDatePickerDialog(getBaseContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog,  datePickerListener, year, month, day);
    DatePickerDialog obj = dp.getPicker();

    picker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    try {
          java.lang.reflect.Field[] f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
  //      Field f[] = picker.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (java.lang.reflect.Field field : f) {
            if (field.getName().equals("prabs")) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) field.get(obj);
                java.lang.reflect.Field datePickerFields[] = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                for (java.lang.reflect.Field datePickerField : datePickerFields) {
                    if ("mYearPicker".equals(datePickerField.getName()) || "mYearSpinner".equals(datePickerField
                            .getName()))
                    {
                             datePickerField.setAccessible(true);
                             Object yearPicker = new Object();
                             yearPicker = datePickerField.get(datePicker);
                             ((View) yearPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
           /*     Object yearPicker = new Object();
                yearPicker = field.get(picker);
                ((View) yearPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);*/
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    } 
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    } 
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    }
    obj.show();
}
```

outside the main class::

```
class CustomDatePickerDialog extends DatePickerDialog implements OnDateChangedListener
{
    private DatePickerDialog prabs;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public CustomDatePickerDialog(Context context, int theme,
            OnDateSetListener listener, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) 
    {
        super(context, theme, listener, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        prabs = new DatePickerDialog(context, theme, listener, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        prabs.getDatePicker().init(2015, 01, 8, this);  
        updateTitle(monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);
    }

    private void updateTitle(int Month, int Day)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Month);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Day);
        prabs.setTitle(getFormat().format(mCalendar.getTime()));
    }

    public SimpleDateFormat  getFormat() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new SimpleDateFormat("MMM, dd");
    }

    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view,int year, int month,int day)
    {
        updateTitle(month,day);
    }

    public DatePickerDialog getPicker()
    {
        return this.prabs;
    }
}
```

before adding `obj.show();` it was displaying the entire widget with calender,but I want only widget with date and month

trying to solve this from many days. But failed every time :(
Any suggestions would be of great help..
Thank you..

EDIT::

year field means the date picker widget's year field of  eclipse

I referred [How to display year only in date picker in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793811/how-to-display-year-only-in-date-picker-in-android) and [Custom Date Picker Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249608/custom-date-picker-dialog)

Error log::

```
01-09 11:26:20.780: E/AndroidRuntime(23840): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application this is a crash report
```

Comment: can any one help regarding this

Comment: still this task is troubling :/

Comment: what you are having issue with this code and secondly if you are having crash with this also paste crash log here that will help better in investigation an issue

Comment: Thank you for your attention @Usman..before adding the obj.show() it was displaying the widget with calender but not it is not even going to that page,,..am not able to trace where is going wrong

Comment: what device you are testing on ?

Comment: on nexus7..am not using emulator because am not able to set that @UsmanKurd

Comment: try it with other then nexus

Comment: 01-09 11:26:20.780: E/AndroidRuntime(23840): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
this is a crash report..tried in samsung

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me.

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        // hide year from datepicker
        DatePickerDialog dlg = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                datePickerListener, year, month, day) {
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                int year = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(
                        "android:id/year", null, null);
                if (year != 0) {
                    View yearPicker = findViewById(year);
                    if (yearPicker != null) {
                        yearPicker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        return dlg;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your time @MEENAXI..let me give a try.,.

Comment: onCreate method should come within DatePickerDialog ??then how how to manage the main class @MEENAXI

Comment: That link is not giving any information regarding how to hide a widget field..its all about set and change data..I referred [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249608/custom-date-picker-dialog) but it is not hiding year field

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
mDialog = new CustomerDatePickerDialog(getContext(), this,
cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
mDialog.show();
DatePicker dp = findDatePicker((ViewGroup) mDialog.getWindow().getDecorView());
if (dp != null) {
((ViewGroup) dp.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

CustomerDatePickerDialog

```
class CustomerDatePickerDialog extends DatePickerDialog {
 public CustomerDatePickerDialog(Context context, OnDateSetListener callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
     super(context, callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
 }

 @Override
 public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
     super.onDateChanged(view, year, month, day);
     mDialog.setTitle((month + 1) + "-" + day + "-");
 }
}
```

DAtePicker

```
   private DatePicker findDatePicker(ViewGroup group) {
    if (group != null) {
        for (int i = 0, j = group.getChildCount(); i < j; i++) {
            View child = group.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof DatePicker) {
                return (DatePicker) child;
            } else if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                DatePicker result = findDatePicker((ViewGroup) child);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

Comment: THank you @Johnson let me give a try

Comment: @Johnson..sorry for the trouble but what is mDialog here..it is giving 2 errors at mDialog..1)within class CustomerDatePickerDialog 2)at 2nd line--                                              [mDialog = new CustomerDatePickerDialog....] so i changed that to [CustomerDatePickerDialog mDialog = new CustomerDatePickerDialog....] then that error gone...now another error is at getContext()...and i've placed this code within my main class "onCreate"

Comment: @user4050065 year selection got disabled. But i can able to scroll and select the different years in my lollipop version of the device.